# I can't open eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I can't open my Eclipse. When I am opening it from terminal, it shows me the following error:

```
(java:3312): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkDisplayManager'

(java:3312): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `initialization_value != 0' failed

(java:3312): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

(java:3312): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(java:3312): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(java:3312): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(java:3312): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(java:3312): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkDisplay'

(java:3312): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `initialization_value != 0' failed

(java:3312): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion `parent_type > 0' failed

(java:3312): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `initialization_value != 0' failed

(java:3312): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f10648bfd41, pid=3312, tid=139708783437568
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b02
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x4fd41]  gdk_display_open+0x41
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/jay/hs_err_pid3312.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Which Eclipse and Ubuntu version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Bug Report which might be related to your problem: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394227. You should try the `-noSplash` command line parameter.

Another possibility is that you need to set the GTK+ version to `2` in *eclipse.ini*. You have to add this line to the configuration file:

> `--launcher.GTK_version`
>   2

Comment: thank you a lot meskobalazs.....i could opened eclipse using "eclipse -noSplash".but what was the problem??

Comment: I don't know exactly, but it is caused by a bug in Eclipse; older versions does not play well with GTK3